# Unable to reference jQuery inside my master page

Tags: jquery, master-page

I am working with SharePoint server 2013, and inside my Style Library folder I have added the Jquery file. then under the  custmJSUrl section inside my seatle.master page, I added a reference to the jQuery file as follows:

```
<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="/sites/Intranet/Style Library/JS/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" runat="server"/>
```

but unfortunately doing so , will stop my page from being displayed and instead of that a blank white page will be displayed  ? so is my approach of referencing jQuery the right way to follow?

Comment: Try having only the `/Style Library/JS/jquery-1.10.2.min.js` in the `Name` property.

Comment: it did not work ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scriptlink is typically reserved for JS files deployed to the file system.

> The ScriptLink will always look in /_LAYOUTS/1033 for the scripts.

http://tommdaly.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/scriptlink-vs-whats-the-difference/

Just change it to the typical `script src="/sites/Intranet/Style Library/JS/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"` syntax or copy the JS files to the /_LAYOUTS/1033 folder on all of your servers.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i added this <script  type="text/javascript" src="/sites/Intranet/Style Library/JS/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script> . should i add extra parameters ?

Comment: no that should be sufficient