# Simple way to implement cascading drop down?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server

I am very new in SharePoint development. when I am doing a task, I got a problem in cascading drop down, so i need to select a value from one drop down depends on another one. i really don't know to solve this problem... i used look up column but it show all values not depend on another... so can any one tell the simple way to do this... and now i have share point designer 2013 only... is it enough or am i need visual studio? Thank for advance.

Comment: You might be able to solve this by __waiting__. It might be coming, see [this image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5V4w2a9GY64/UxYm_bzbuQI/AAAAAAAAJZU/tpeXoiTZIe8/s800/20140304_093645.jpg) which hints to it, ref http://sp2013.blogspot.no/2014/03/infopath-is-dead-long-live-excel-survey.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution from this blog

http://sharepointkids.blogspot.in/2014/04/two-level-cascading-drop-down-in.html

Answer (score 5):

It's not possibile OOB so you have to implement it with javascript or you can use SPServices to do that: https://spservices.codeplex.com

Comment: thank you... and i need basic tutorial about how to add jquery to master page(i am using 2013 sharepoint)

Answer (score 5):

Use SPservices as only SharePoint Designer is enough for it to work. It may not work if list item exceeds list view threshold in some cases. Also it depends lot on browser compatibility of jQuery. But this is simplest method that you can use to do cascading dropdown although its not very reliable

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
  relationshipWebURL: "",
  relationshipList: "",
  relationshipListParentColumn: "",
  relationshipListChildColumn: "",
  relationshipListSortColumn: "",
  parentColumn: "",
  childColumn: "",
  CAMLQuery: "",
  CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns></QueryOptions>", // Added in 2013.01
  listName: $().SPServices.SPListNameFromUrl(), 
  promptText: "",
  simpleChild: false,           // Added in v0.6.2
  selectSingleOption: false,        // Added in v0.6.2
  matchOnId: false,         // Added in v0.7.1
  completefunc: null,
  debug: false
});
```

[Use this for further Reference](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: thank you... and i need basic tutorial about how to add jquery to master page(i am using 2013 sharepoint)

Comment: use this post for that http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78025/unable-to-reference-jquery-inside-my-master-page